# Невозможно подключиться к Derby DB из Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

При создании базы Data Sources -> Derby(Remote).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, при тестовом подключении появляется ошибка

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Derby (embeddad). Если база необходима для локального пользования.

Если же для удаленного, проверьте, подключение к базе, сторонним клиентом. К примеру dbeaver. Если будет ошибка - проблема на стороне базы данных, а не IDE